# Python - creating "if" statement with function and getting return without repetition

Tags: python

This is most likely a very basic question as I just started Python the other day, but I couldn't find any documentation.  I'm practising with a basic text-adventure program.

Here's what I have set up:  The program goes though a course of specific questions.  When the user gives input, that input is put through a function to see if it contains the keyword `inv` (inventory).  If so, the program will display the inventory dictionary.  If not, the function will return the original input value for the program to continue.

Here is my current "info" function

```
def info(s):
inputinventory = s
if inputinventory == 'inv':
    print ('\n###INVENTORY###')  

        #here it would print my dictionary - don't worry about this

    #asks user to input again to continue question if 'inv' has been typed
    info(input())
else:
    #script will return the original input value if 'inv' is not typed
    return inputinventory
```

Implementation of this function:

```
print ('How old are you? ')
if info(input()) == '12':   #just an example
    print ('some example text')
elif info(input()) == '13':  #the troublesome line
    print ('more example text')
```

The problem I am having is that the `elif` statement doesn't work as it should since it requires input.  This is the way I researched to test the value of a return - I can't find out how else to get it without writing the function over and over again to get what it returns.  Is there a way to solve this, or am I making things difficult?

edit:
**Wait - I bet I can just run the function once and assign it to a variable...  Let's try that really quick...** but that won't work if the user types "inv" probably

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to store the return value of `info()` as a variable.

```
print ('How old are you? ')
user_value = info(input()) # store it is a variable
if user_value == '12':
    print ('some example text')
elif user_value == '13':
    print ('more example text') # it works!
```

Comment: This does work fine, except if I first type in "inv" to display the inventory, it no longer displays text.  I'm going to revise my code so I check if 'inv' is entered in a different spot.  But winning answer still, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd want to call input(), and assign the result to a variable, BEFORE any of your ifs; then you test that variable as many ways as you like.

Answer (score 0):

I would actually get a little more sophisticated

```
some_dictionary = {12: 'some example text', 13: 'some other example text', . . . }

print ('How old are you')

user_value = info(input()):

while user_value not in some_dictionary:
    print ('some warning message')
    print (' if you want to exit then type N')
    print ('How old are you')
    user_value = info(input())
    if user_value.upper() == 'N':
         break

if user_value in some_dictionary:
    print some_dictionary[user_value]
```

This way you get closer to making the code simpler and you can more easily modify and extend the code

Comment: This results in an infinite loop if the user does not enter a value in the dictionary. It would keep printing `some warning message` infinitely.

Comment: Thanks I was thinking about the big problem not the details - the story of my life